# Stripe Invalid CVC return 500 server error

Tags: php, wordpress, stripe-payments

I'm trying to implement stripe using wordpress plugin,

everything is working except when user enter invalid CVC it shows 500 error on ajax request.

```
/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 500 Internal Server Error 3.81s
```

It shows validation messages for invalid card number and for invalid expire dates,

I also checked error logs but cannot find any error details.

anyone know what is the reason for that kind of error.Thank You

**PS. I don't expect code solution, just need to know how to debug this error or is there have any specific reason to happen this, if someone experienced this error before**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=php#error_handling

A card decline will throw a `Stripe\Error\Card` exception. If you don't try/catch it, you'll get a 500.

Comment: And as a side note, there *will* be an error message about this *somewhere*. You'll want to find that somewhere, or coding in PHP will be miserable.

Comment: Thanks mate, i checked  stripe return 402 code which send to PHP "Exception" class using stripe api function, it seems PHP "Exception" class return 500 error, I'll try to fix that :)